# Using RecurrenceTable index to call elements of a vector

Tags: recursion

I am having trouble doing something that seems straightforward. I have a recursive sequence that I would like to produce which looks as follows:

```
a2 = {1, 2, 3}
RecurrenceTable[{a1[n + 1] == a1[n] + a2[[n]], a1[1] == 1}, a1, {n, 1, 3}]
```

This seems like it should work, but *Mathematica* is complaining about `n` not being an integer when I try to call the $n$-th part of `a2`. What I am really interested in is a very large `RecurrenceTable` of this form rather than what I have posted. Since `RecurrenceTable` seems to be much more efficient at generating large recursive sequences than any other functions I have been able to find, I would love to find a way to be able to use it.

Comment: Do you mean to have both `a` and `a1`?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
a2List = {1, 2, 3};
a2[n_Integer] := a2List[[n]];

RecurrenceTable[{a1[n + 1] == a1[n] + a2[n], a1[1] == 1}, a1, {n, 1, 4}]
   {1, 2, 4, 7}
```

OTOH, for this particular case, `Fold[]` is more expedient:

```
FoldList[Plus, 1, {1, 2, 3}]
   {1, 2, 4, 7}
```

Comment: For this particular case: Accumulate[a2] + 1

Comment: Indeed, `Accumulate[]` is even better. (Sadly, I still haven't shaken off the habit of remembering `Accumulate[]` as the old name for `Fold[]`...)

Answer (score 1):

While `Fold` or `Accumulate` are probably better solutions for this specific problem, depending on your larger problem you might also want to consider a recursive approach, which can be written in a similar form to your original problem statement.

```
b = {1, 2, 4, 3, 2};
a[n_] := a[n - 1] + b[[n]];
a[0] := 0;
```

With these definitions, you can calculate the values of `a` using

```
a /@ Range[Length[b]]
```

which gives `{1, 3, 7, 10, 12}` as expected.

For larger problems you might also want to "memoize" this, which is a technique for storing past values of the function instead of recalculating them on-the-fly. For this, you would use

```
    a[n_] := a[n] = a[n - 1] + b[[n]];
```